# I am trying to provide Google Calendar with Url of Calendar served By IIS (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar

When i put the .ics file in a folder of the site and use it's URL Google recognize it and visualize it as well, but when i try to serve the file Via Action google does not do anything.

Thats what i have so far:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    public FileResult Test()
    {
        byte[] calendarBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"<filename>", Encoding.UTF8));

        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = "Test.ics",
            Inline = true,
        };

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        return File(calendarBytes, "text/calendar");
    }
```

The .ics file looks like this

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:eTemida
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:eTemida_Web
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Sofia
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180301T140000Z
DTEND:20180301T143000Z
DTSTAMP:20180228T145800Z
UID:9358d70d-d1bf-45ea-8f40-321be757dda6
CREATED:20180228T145600Z
DESCRIPTION:eTemida
LASTMODIFIED:20180228T145600Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:eTemida
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180302T123000Z
DTEND:20180302T130000Z
DTSTAMP:20180228T145800Z
UID:9cdd0d9e-891c-4b33-ada8-cf4c7b50b479
CREATED:20180228T145700Z
DESCRIPTION:eTemida
LASTMODIFIED:20180228T145700Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:eTemida
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180302T140000Z
DTEND:20180302T143000Z
DTSTAMP:20180228T145800Z
UID:be32b65f-7435-4544-8c58-8068f8847345
CREATED:20180228T145700Z
DESCRIPTION:eTemida
LASTMODIFIED:20180228T145700Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:eTemida
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I dont have any hint about what to do ? 
Is it because its served via FTP from the server and via HTTP from the Controller's Action ?

**EDIT**

I'm using 'From Url' option on 'Add Other Calendars' button

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Google recognize it"? How is Google interacting with anything here?

Comment: When you're writing action methods, don't manipulate the Response directly. That defeats the point of using MVC.

Comment: Try just rendering the ICS content as text rather than sending as an attachment for download. In other words just return a string basically. Also a Web API controller might be more suited for this an an MVC one.

Comment: I'm using 'From Url' option on 'Add Other Calendars' button

Comment: I suggest you clarify that in your question then. Next, look at the response you get (e.g. in Fiddler) when serving it directly vs from an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCalendar()
    {
        string IcsFileData = EventsManager.GenerateCalendarString();

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(IcsFileData)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline")
            {
                FileName = "Calendar.ics"
            };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/calendar");

        return result;
    }
```